# Criar uma variável global no Delphi

Tags: delphi

Preciso executar o seguinte código, porém o formulário em questão nem sempre é *UniForm1*. Então penso em armazenar o nome do `form` numa variável e substituir o *UniForm1* por ela.

Em vez de usar:

```
UniForm1.Parent := UniPanel1;
UniForm1.Show;
UniForm1.SetFocus;

UniForm1.Width := UniPanel1.Width;
UniForm1.Height := UniPanel1.Height;
```

Preciso de algo como:

```
VariavelForm.Parent := UniPanel1;
VariavelForm.Show;
VariavelForm.SetFocus;

VariavelForm.Width := UniPanel1.Width;
VariavelForm.Height := UniPanel1.Height;
```

Como fazer isso?

Conforme a resposta de @Tmc, fiz algumas alterações.

Porém ocorre o erro:

> [dcc32 Error] Main.pas(74): E2010 Incompatible types: 'TUniForm' and
>   'string'

```
procedure TMainForm.UniTreeView1Change(Sender: TObject; Node: TUniTreeNode);
var nome : string;
begin
   nome := Node.Text;

   Vforms := nome;

   Vforms.Parent := UniPanel1;
   Vforms.Show;
   Vforms.SetFocus;

   Vforms.Width := UniPanel1.Width;
   Vforms.Height := UniPanel1.Height;
end;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms, Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  private
    procedure ChangeSetForms;
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
    //declarar variavel global
    Vforms: TComponent;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text := 'Form1';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  // atribui valor de form a variavel
  Vforms := Application.FindComponent(Edit1.Text);

  //chama a procedure
  ChangeSetForms;
end;

procedure TForm1.ChangeSetForms;
Begin
  //faz as alterãções no form escolhido
  TForm(VForms).Parent := UniPanel1;
  TForm(VForms).Show;
  TForm(VForms).SetFocus;

  TForm(VForms).Width := UniPanel1.Width;
  TForm(VForms).Height := UniPanel1.Height;
End;

end.
```

Tentei detalhar todos os passos mas alguma dúvida estou disponível.

Outra hipótese é não criar uma variável chamando o `procedure` e passando a variável por ele, deixo também o exemplo:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Edit1.Text := 'Form1';
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  //chama a procedure
  ChangeSetForms(Application.FindComponent(Edit1.Text));
end;

procedure TForm1.ChangeSetForms(VForm: TComponent);
Begin
  TForm(VForm).Width := 500;
End;
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66127/discussion-on-answer-by-tmc-criar-uma-variavel-global-no-delphi)